# swift 1.2でのtouchesの処理

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

swift1.2での質問です。
http://qiita.com/phptaro/items/83e345ebab457a35d006
このサイトを参考にさせていただき、コードを書いていました。
swift1.2になってから、以下のコードの部分でエラーができるようになってしまいました。

> Overriding method with selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' has incompatible type '(NSSet, UIEvent) -> ()'
>   Overriding method with selector 'touchesMoved:withEvent:' has incompatible type '(NSSet, UIEvent) -> ()'

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    lastPoint = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var newPoint = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)
    lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint!))
    lastPoint = newPoint

    self.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

いくつか他のサイトを参考にさせていただき、

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {..}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {..}
```

に書き換えたのですが、なかなかnewPointやlastPointと型が合わずに困っています。
教えていただけたら幸いです。お願いします。

補足：Lineのクラスはこのようになっています。

```
class Line {
var start: CGPoint
var end: CGPoint

init(start _start: CGPoint, end _end:CGPoint){
    start = _start
    end = _end
}}
```

Comment: 書き換え後のコードも提示してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のコードを参考にしてください。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.first as? UITouch
        var position = CGPointZero
        if let _touch = touch {
            position = _touch.locationInView(self.view)
        }
        println("Touch Position = \(position)")
    }

}
```

ポイントは、

1. 型Setには、NSSetクラスの「anyObject()」に対応するメソッド、プロパティが存在しない。上記コードでは、Set「touches」の先頭メンバー（`first`）を取り出している。
2. `touchesBegan`、`touchesMoved`の引数では、Setの要素の型が「NSObject」になります。NSObjectには、`locationInView()`というメソッドがないので、エラーが出ます。正しくNSObjectをUITouchクラスに型キャストする必要があります。C言語、Objective-Cでは、暗黙的な型キャストをしてくれた場面でも、Swiftでは、手動で明示的な型キャストをする必要が出てきます。
3. これはおまけですが、Optional型変数に対応した処理もするようにしてください。Setの要素は、ここではOptional型です。